# Can't access the values posted by jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a an script that sends a post to my php file:

```
$('.target').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/form-actions.php",
        data: {rechten : '0'},
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            alert("Submitted");
       }
    });
});
```

When i use firebug i can see the post being send: **Parameter: rechten 0**

But my form-actions.php (which is in the right location) can't see the post when i use

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

The outcome of this is **Array ( )**

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: how do u see that your form-actions.php does not contain the post data? Where do you expect to see it?

Comment: try echo $_POST['rechten'];

Comment: change `data: {rechten : '0'}` to `data: {'rechten' : '0'}`.

Comment: @luk2302 - That shouldn't matter - especially as Firebug is reporting the data as sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm adding this as an answer rather than a comment because of the code)
Are you super-sure your php file is in the right place?
Change your JS to

```
$('.target').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/form-actions.php",
        data: {rechten : '0'},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
       }
    });
});
```

And see what is alerted.

This is assuming that form-actions.php contains just

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

and nothing else (or you'll see that too).

Comment: When i use your code this is what i see in my alertbox Array([rechten] => 0)